# jQuery find from another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my codes:

```
$('.user-url').hover(function() {
    var element = $(this).find('.dropdown-menu');
    element.css({ 'visibility' : 'visible' });
});

<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle">
        <h5 class="the-info">
            <a class="user-url">
                Test
            </a>
        </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu"></div>
</div>
```

How to find .dropdown-menu class when hover on .author-url from .dropdown class without lose $(this) functionality?

My code not working except if I replace .user-url class to .dropdown.

Comment: `$(this).closest(".dropdown").find(".dropdown-menu")`

Comment: This is like the 4th question like this today.... find looks for children.... The element you are looking for is NOT a child.

Comment: You'll never be a proficient jQuery programmer if you don't learn how all the DOM traversal methods work. Study https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your advice, i am still learning javascript by trying and learn from my mistakes.

Comment: There are good books and tutorials, you don't have to learn it by trial and error.

Comment: `$(this).closest(".dropdown-toggle").siblings(".dropdown-menu")` another way to find that set.  Different ways to traverse. `$(this).parent().parent().siblings(".dropdown-menu")` - if you change structure this breaks. or for fun `$(this).parent().parent().next(".dropdown-menu")` since it follows the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is:** You use `$(this).find('.dropdown-menu');` but `user-url` doesn't have a child `dropdown-menu` the `dropdown-menu` is child of `dropdown` and `user-url` is under `dropdown`

**To solve this:** you need to use `.closest()` to find the parent `dropdown` and `.find()` to find a child `dropdown-menu` .. so you need to use this code

```
$(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-menu');
```

Comment: @AhmedMohamed You're welcome .. and if you're a beginner in jquery I highly recommend [Jquery tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810)  yes its 200 videos but its very simple.. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 2):

Jquery find() looks down the tree. .dropdown-menu is outside of dropdown-toggle. So you need to do.

```
$('.user-url').hover(function() {
    var element = $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-menu');
    element.css({ 'visibility' : 'visible' });
});
```

Comment: If you even post you're answer in the same time of mine .. but you have a right answer too .. +1 :-) .. have a great day :)

Comment: I gave you a plus one too!

Comment: Thanks .. you deserve  +1 too may be on another accepted answer :-)) .. good luck :)